# How to display the names in different color if found in array

Tags: javascript

I have got an array of  values

```
var prevaluesarray = ["TWO", "FOUR"]
var all_wl = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"];
```

I am looping through all_wl values , if any one found in prevaluesarray , i want to print it in gren color

```
var all_wl = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"];
var html = '';
var value = '22';
var prevaluesarray = ["TWO", "FOUR"]
for (var i = 0; i < all_wl.length; i++) {
    var name = all_wl[i];
    var found = $.inArray(name, prevaluesarray) > -1;
    if (found) {
        alert(name);
    }
    html += '<tr>\
                            <td class="text-center"><label for="' + name + '" class="marg_none"><div></div></label></td>\n\
                            <td>' + name + '</td>\n\
                            <td>' + value + '</td>\n\
                        </tr>';
}
$("#positivebody").append(html);
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bhmL6yvc/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wxsoqtwc/1/

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with this? You forgot to mention what's wrong with your code. :)

Comment: This is not a question, or the question is stated unclearly.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 The question is in the title, whats missing is an explanation what fails for him (maybe).

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks a lot simple and working fine .

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var all_wl = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"];
    var html = '';
    var value = '22';
    var prevaluesarray = ["TWO", "FOUR"]
    for (var i = 0; i < all_wl.length; i++) {
        var name = all_wl[i];
        var found = $.inArray(name, prevaluesarray) > -1;
        if (found) {
            //console.log(name);
            name = '<b>'+all_wl[i]+'</b>';
            value= '<b>'+value+'</b>';
        }
        html += '<tr>\
                                <td class="text-center"><label for="' + name + '" class="marg_none"><div></div></label></td>\n\
                                <td>' + name + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + value + '</td>\n\
                            </tr>';
    }
    $("#positivebody").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped marg_none" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th  data-sorter="false" width="1%"></th>
            <th  data-sorter="false"  width="18.8%">Name </th>
            <th width="18.8%">Difference</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="positivebody">
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```